# Issue in connecting Apache Drill using JDBC - Invalid RPC exception

Tags: javascript, jdbc, apache-drill

We have some errors in Apache Drill - JDBC connection. We have recently upgraded to `Apache Drill 1.0` and the same application works till `Drill 0.8`.
 I am attaching the exception below:

```
org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.RpcException: Failure connecting to server. Failure of type HANDSHAKE_VALIDATION.
            at org.apache.drill.exec.client.DrillClient$FutureHandler.connectionFailed(DrillClient.java:376)
            at org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.BasicClient$ConnectionMultiListener$HandshakeSendHandler.success(BasicClient.java:184)
            at org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.BasicClient$ConnectionMultiListener$HandshakeSendHandler.success(BasicClient.java:167)
            at org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.CoordinationQueue$RpcListener.set(CoordinationQueue.java:97)
            at org.apache.drill.exec.rpc

Caused by: org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.RpcException: Invalid rpc version.  Expected 5, actual 3.
        at org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.user.UserClient.validateHandshake(UserClient.java:105)
        at org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.user.UserClient.validateHandshake(UserClient.java:43)
        at org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.BasicClient$ConnectionMultiListener$HandshakeSendHandler.success(BasicClient.java:179)
        ... 25 more
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is because of a jdbc version mismatch. We have kept in the correct war and it worked.